# Передача переменной внутрь двойных кавычек JQuery, метод .load()

Tags: javascript, jquery

Есть работающая функция

```
 function ocmenu( p ){
   $( "#container2" ).load( "1.html #content" );
 }
```

Пытаюсь передать номер html страницы "1" с помощью переменной с моего же сайта, но ничего не получается. Пробовал через конкатенацию строк - полная тщета.

```
$( "#container2" ).load( \""\" +p+ ".html" + " " + "#content" + \""\" );
```

Переменную передаю через OnClick

```
<p onclick="ocmenu('1')">ClickClack</p>
```

Comment: $( "#container2" ).load( p + ".html #content" ); p + ".html #content" - должно конвертировать в строку и получится валидный параметр для load

Comment: Большое спасибо! Заработало, оказалось все еще проще ;)

Comment: слишком много экранирования, слишком много кавычек

Answer (score 1):

так как динамичная часть строки, просто вначале можно воспользоваться советом из комментария

```
p + ".html #content"
```

В случае когда подстановок несколько в разных местах можно воспользоваться [шаблонами, которые добавились в ES2015](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals)(не работают в IE)

В данном случае они выглядели бы так:

```
`${p}.html #content`
```