# Добавление элемента на страницу

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

```
var images=["5.jpg","4.jpg","7.jpg","4.jpg","7.jpg","5.jpg"]
for (var i = 0; i < images.length; i++) {
    $(".stripe").after("<img src='images[i]' class='stripe1'>")
};
```

Как мне указать правильный путь к картинке из массива?

Comment: $(".stripe").after("<img src='images[i]' class='stripe1'>")- правильная строчка

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Передача переменной внутрь двойных кавычек JQuery, метод .load()](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/529610/%d0%9f%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b4%d0%b0%d1%87%d0%b0-%d0%bf%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b9-%d0%b2%d0%bd%d1%83%d1%82%d1%80%d1%8c-%d0%b4%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%b9%d0%bd%d1%8b%d1%85-%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%b2%d1%8b%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%ba-jquery-%d0%bc%d0%b5%d1%82%d0%be%d0%b4-load)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`"<img src='images[i]' class='stripe1'>"` - `JS` **не** интерполирует переменные хоть в одинарных, хоть в двойных кавычках.
Новый синтаксис шаблонов ( **`** ) может это делать:

```
`<img src='${images[i]}' class='stripe1'>`
```

Впрочем, шаблоны старые браузеры не поддерживают, тогда можно так:

```
"<img src='" + images[i] + "' class='stripe1'>"
```

Comment: Спасибо тут выражается в плюсах к карме и принятии ответа для будущих поколений (галка рядом с ответом).